# UITableview: Attempt to delete and reload the same index path (<NSIndexPath: 0xa8d9c10c8af4b9b4> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0})

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am new to iOS coding. I attempted to delete the only row in my UITableview and received the following error "Attempt to delete and reload the same index path (<NSIndexPath: 0xa8d9c10c8af4b9b4> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0})". I looked for similar threads - it seems like this was bug that was identified a couple of years ago, but, I don't seem to see that issue reported recently so I was wondering if I was doing something wrong. Your help would be much appreciated!

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      
            if editingStyle == .delete {
             
                    let len = displayList.count
                    displayList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
              
                  //  self.totTableView.beginUpdates()
                    if displayTotList.count == len - 1{

                        totTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                        totTableView.reloadData()
                        
                    }
             
                   // self.totTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
                //    self.totTableView.endUpdates()
                        
           }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If displayTotList is your dataSource, you can just reload data, after removed an item from displayList, without deletingRows.
Or if you want an animation of deletion, you can deleteRows without reloadingData